# How to find application (Java) in PATH in Inno Setup

Tags: java, windows, inno-setup

I can use **cmd commands** like `set PATH` to return value of `PATH` environment or `set JAVA` to return `JAVA_HOME` path variable value.

Similarly, in **Inno Setup** we can use `'ExpandConstant({%PATH|DefaultValue})'` to get path variable value list.

**My requirement is :** If user is using zip version of `JRE` so there won't be any entry in registry. So, I'll have to read the `PATH` variable **or** `JAVA_HOME` to get the path of Java.

**Problem :** Getting the value from `JAVA_HOME` is quite easy but I want to extract specific path from the list of `path` values, for ex: if user is not using `JAVA_HOME` and instead using the complete path in path variable like : `PATH=c:\program files\jre\bin`, I want to extract only this JRE path instead of entire list. Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: Is short, do you want to retrieve the path from `PATH` environment that contains string `'JRE'`?

Comment: Hey @MartinPrikryl, Yes but the folder name would be like jre1.8.0_171(path = c:/program files/jre1.8.0_171/bin). I don't want to hard code the version 1.8.0_171.

Comment: Exactly, I want to retrieve the path from PATH environment that contains string 'JRE'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest (and even the correct) way is to find the path, where `java.exe` is.

You can use [`FileSearch` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filesearch), like:

```pascal
var
  Path: string;
begin
  Path := FileSearch('java.exe', GetEnv('PATH'));
  if Path = '' then
  begin
    Log('Java not found in PATH');
  end
    else
  begin
    Path := ExtractFileDir(Path);
    Log(Format('Java is in "%s"', [Path]));
  end;
end;
```

---

If you still want to take the way of looking for a path that contains `JRE`, you can use a code like this:

```pascal
var
  Path: string;
  JavaPath: string;
  S: string;
  P: Integer;
begin
  Path := GetEnv('PATH');
  while (Path <> '') and (JavaPath = '') do
  begin
    P := Pos(';', Path);
    if P = 0 then
    begin
      S := Trim(Path);
      Path := '';
    end
      else
    begin
      S := Trim(Copy(Path, 1, P - 1));
      Path := Trim(Copy(Path, P + 1, Length(Path) - P)); 
    end;

    if Pos('JDK', Uppercase(S)) > 0 then
    begin
      JavaPath := S;
    end;
  end;

  if JavaPath = '' then
  begin
    Log('Java not found in PATH');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Java is in "%s"', [JavaPath]));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help @Martin Prikryl !!.  It initially detected Oracle Java path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"  then I moved my actual java path before the Oracle Java path , then it worked. so, yes there is a condition, you java path has to be set at the beginning of all paths.

Comment: And is it a problem that it detected `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`? It's also Java path, isn't it?

Comment: checking the location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java", I found only three files java.exe, javaw.exe, javaws.exe. If i set this java path for my tomcat installation, will it work? It needs JVM.dll file so don't think it would work Anyway thanks for a quick solution.

Comment: I do not have enough experience with Java to answer that. Though you can search for `server\JVM.dll` instead of `java.exe`, if you believe that you need `JVM.dll`.

Comment: your solution at least gives me an idea, how it can be done on Pascal/Inno setup. This can be improved and I'm gonna work on this and modify it to meet my requirements. So, thank you for such a quick solution, I really appreciate your help.